# how to hide the text-adjustment while window resize in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code of website here

```js
document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "165px";
var mini = true;
function toggleSidebar() {

  if (mini) {
    console.log("opening sidebar");
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar2").style.width = "0px";

    this.mini = false;
  } else {
    console.log("closing sidebar");
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "85px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "165px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "85px";
     document.getElementById("mySidebar2").style.width = "165px";

    this.mini = true;
  }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }
  #mySidebar{
    display:block;

  }
  #circularMenu1{
    display:none;
  }

  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .sidebar2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

  .sidebar a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }

  .sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  main .sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

  .material-icons,
  .icon-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .material-icons {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  #main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s;

  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidebar a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 599px){

body {
  background-color:#26394E ;
}
.circular-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
#mySidebar{
  display:none;
}
#circularMenu1{
  display:block;
}

.circular-menu .floating-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FED057;hsl(4, 98%, 60%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .26);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.9;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.circular-menu.active .floating-btn {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .3);
}

.circular-menu .floating-btn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4);
}

.circular-menu .floating-btn i {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.circular-menu.active .floating-btn i {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.circular-menu:after {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  /*background-color: hsl(4, 98%, 60%);*/
  transition: all .5s ease;
}



.circular-menu .items-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.rotate-30{ transform: rotate(30deg); }
.rotate-60{ transform: rotate(60deg);}
.rotate-90{ transform: rotate(90deg);}

.circular-menu .menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;

  line-height: 3;
  background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
  transition: transform 1s ease;/*, background .2s ease;*/
}


.circular-menu .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.3);
  transform: scale(2);

}


.circular-menu.active .menu-item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}


.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-210px)  scale(1);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-210px)  scale(1.1);
  color:red;
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(330deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.1);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: rotate(330deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.2);
  color:red;
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform:  rotate(300deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.2);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(3):hover {
  transform:  rotate(300deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.3);
  color:red;
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.3);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(4):hover {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-210px) scale(1.4);
  color:red;
}
}


/**
 * The other theme for this menu
 */
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="s21.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <style media="screen">



  </style>
  <body>
  <!--  <div id="circularMenu" class="circular-menu">

  <a class="floating-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('circularMenu').classList.toggle('active');">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </a>

  <menu class="items-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="menu-item fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item fa fa-google-plus"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item fa fa-linkedin"></a>
  </menu>

</div>-->


<div id="circularMenu1" class="circular-menu circular-menu-left">

  <a class="floating-btn" onclick="myFunction();">
    <i id="yup" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  <menu class="items-wrapper">

      <a href="#" class="menu-item "><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>


    <a href="#" class="menu-item "><i style="margin-left:7px;" class="fa fa-user rotate-30"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item "><i style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;" class="fa fa-info  rotate-60"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item "><i style="margin-top:40px;padding-right:2px;" class="fa fa-cog  rotate-90"></i></a>
  </menu>

</div>




<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()">
  <a href="#"><span><i class="material-icons">info</i><span class="icon-text">about</span></a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">spa</i><span class="icon-text"></span>services</a></span>
  </a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i><span class="icon-text"></span>clients</span></a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">email</i><span class="icon-text"></span>contact<span></a>
</div>

<div id="main">

  <p>To close the sidebar, move your mouse out of the sidebar.The side navigation component provides an easy way to navigate through your website. Its appearance & behaviour are easily adjustable with data-mdb-attributes and methods - additional functionality such as touch events and focus trap (in an over mode) are available out of the box.

Note: Read the API tab to find all available options and advanced customization

Video tutorial


Note: This component requires MDB Pro Essential package.


Basic example
In the basic version, the side navigation will appear over your website's content after clicking on a toggler.

Note: Use show and hide methods to toggle navigation with JavaScript.

Note: Adding the show class to a sidenav collapse element will expand this category on render.

Link 1
Category 1
Link 2
Link 3
Category 2

Access restricted
To view this code you must have an MDB Pro account

Purchase MDB Pro if you are a new user or Log in if you already have it


Positioning
While using the side and push modes, you can specify the selector for your page's content - this way, the component will automatically update paddings and margins. To customize this behaviour in a non-standard way, use a combination of media queries & update.mdb.sidenav event

Select mode:

Link 1
Category 1
Category 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc magna massa, ornare quis interdum a, cursus in quam. Quisque risus libero, cursus eget eros vitae, aliquam placerat velit. Vivamus luctus eros id sagittis luctus. Pellentesque felis nulla, rhoncus viverra nunc vitae, viverra aliquam ante. Ut feugiat mattis tempor.

Access restricted
To view this code you must have an MDB Pro account

Purchase MDB Pro if you are a new user or Log in if you already have it


Colors example
Setting the color attribute will change the background and font color of active/hovered links and categories.

Note: This option works for MDB 5 main colors - primary, secondary, warning, danger, success, info, dark and light.

Select color:


Link 1
Category 1
Category 2

Access restricted
To view this code you must have an MDB Pro account

Purchase MDB Pro if you are a new user or Log in if you already have it


Dark example
When using the darker background with the side navigation, we recommend setting the color attribute to "light" for better contrast.

Link 1
Category 1
Category 2

Acce</p>
</div>

<div id="mySidebar2" class="sidebar2" style="width:165px">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('circularMenu1').classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('yup').classList.toggle("fa-times");

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
```

it has two sidenavs ,one on right and one on left. when one shows,other one collapses.The text in between however get readjusted,but i have set the widths such that if remains unaffected by the open and collapse of sidenavs. But the text-adjustment while the navs open is what i want to remove.

I want that the text moves smoothly to the right when the left nav opens and come back smothly when left nav closes. please guide me what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `transition: margin-left 0.5s` in your `#main` in your CSS to `transition: all 0.5s`.

So you have the following in your CSS file:

```
  #main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
```